# What defines the plane of an accretion disk around a black hole?

Tags: black-hole, supermassive-black-hole, accretion-discs

The question [Do we know at which angle the Event Horizon Telescope will look at the accretion disk of Sagittarius A*?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/26987/7982) about just how close to edge-on we would be viewing any accretion disk around the black hole in the center of our galaxy, and @Zephyr's [excellent answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/26988/7982) have got be thinking about the geometry and angular momentum.

While the angular momentum vector of a black hole will likely reflect that of all the matter that fell into it , would the plane of any accretion disk around a black hole reflect the black hole's *current equatorial plane*, or a plane defined by rotation of whatever material is currently falling in to it?

Another way to formulate this question might be to propose an incredibly unlikely [Gedankenexperiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_experiment). If I inserted a black hole into the center of a rotating disk of material so that the black hole's axis *was in the plane of the disk of material* rather than parallel to its rotational axis, would a well-defined accretion disk form all all, and if so, what would determine the orientation of that plane?

Comment: I think your question would be better served if it was phrased differently. As it is, it seems like you're asking if *any* black hole can have the configuration you describe (which it could). Perhaps the better question is to ask about a specific black hole or ask about what the population of black holes are like overall.

Comment: @zephyr I'm trying to find out which tends to defines the orientation of the plane of a black hole's accretion disk, the plane of rotation of the in-falling matter, or the plane of the black hole's equator, or both, or if they are significantly misaligned, would that just not lead to a well-formed disk to begin with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me give an answer based on my intuitive understanding of the thing...

#### Initial conditions

The initial accretion disk movement is defined by the objects falling into it, the black hole's mass and its spin of course.

If you take the situation where a single star falls on a quiet black-hole, the accretion will appear along the orbit of the infalling object.

[image]
<sup>Credit: NASA, S. Gezari (The Johns Hopkins University, Baltimore, Md.), A. Rest (Space Telescope Science Institute, Baltimore, Md.), and R. Chornock (Harvard-Smithsonian Center for Astrophysics, Cambridge, Ma.)</sup> and live on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpaVzOKihBQ)...

#### Equilibrium in an active galactic nucleus

Now on the long run, if additional matter is constantly coming in, at first thought I would think

- the accretion disk momentum will be exchanged with the one of the black hole through the [Penrose process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_process),
- Infalling matter momentum will reflect the overall host galaxy momentum - especially if the galaxy is a spiral

Comment: fyi I have just asked [Has the Penrose process ever been linked to an observed phenomenon in some way?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/27298/7982)